# How to control the result of a json_encode?

Tags: php, xampp, json

i have this simple php code. Locally, with a simple xampp 1.7.3 the echo returns correctly `"false" or "true"`. When i put the code online (on a server, i mean, and i do not have really knowdledge of how the server is made) it returns always "1". Why?

```
<?php

include "connectionToDb.php";


$nome_utente=$_GET['nome_utente'];

$queryUserAvailable = "SELECT * FROM utente where nome_utente='$nome_utente'";

$rsUserAvailable = connetti($queryUserAvailable);


if(mysql_num_rows($rsUserAvailable) == 0){
$valid=true;

}

else{
$valid=false;

}


echo json_encode($valid);

?>
```

ConnectionToDb.php

```
<?php
function connetti($SQL){
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //(online this data are obviously different)
$db = mysql_select_db("dbName",$conn);
$risultato = mysql_query($SQL,$conn)
 or die("Query non valida: " . mysql_error());
return ($risultato);
}
?>
```

Comment: did some tests. The connection works well for the if works correctly. The json encode of $valid returns "true" locally and nothing online...

Comment: Are you SURE the code on the server is EXACTLY the same as on the local system? What are the PHP versions? Use `phpinfo();` to find out.

Comment: By the way, when you say `"true"` ... Are the `"` quotes included in the output?

Comment: Also, when looking at the results of `phpinfo();` on the server, check if `mysql` is present in the output. Also check if `json` is present in the output. Check if JSON is **enabled**. And tell us what the JSON version is.

Comment: the quote are not included. Phpinfo says: Locally php 5.3.1 json enabled. Online php 5.1.6 json never ever mentioned. So this is the problem! Json is not enabled! Perhaps i can contact the owner of the server and ask him to enable it. It will be a difficult thing? By the way thank you so much! If you convert the comment into an answer i will be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems from the comments, JSON is not included in the server's PHP configuration.
You might want to consult your host and check whether you can include this by just overriding settings via a `.htaccess` directive

Maybe you can also first try:

```
if (!extension_loaded('json')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        dl('json.dll');
    } else {
        dl('json.so');
    }
}
```

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, in order to check the problem i had to do a phpinfo to verify if json was enabled. Thank you very much for the precious help ^^

Comment: check my edit btw. maybe this code-solution will help you... but its not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Surely i'll do and i'll make you know! Thank you!